# SVN command for recommit the revert changes based on revision number

Tags: linux, svn

I reverted the committed files using svn command

```
svn merge -r:73:68 http://my.repository.com/my/project/trunk
svn commit -m "Reverted to revision 68."
```

I have to recommit the revision number 73 changes again, is that possible?

Comment: yes this will revert.

Comment: Yep I did, If I have to commit those reverted files?

Comment: Yes you have to commit those reverted files.

Comment: Can I commit that revision number 73 changes  again, which I reverted  and commited

Comment: If the reversion was the only change in that commit, then you can revert the entire commit by `svn merge -c -<revision that I committed to revert to revision 68> .` and then committing

Comment: @Petesh Thanks your command helped to do what i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

> I have to recommit the revision number 73 changes again, is that
>   possible?

You can't and you don't have to. One of the key features of SVN is that revision history in Subversion repository is immutable.

You can't rewrite the history of changes, but there should be no problems to commit this change as a new revision.

Read [SVNBook | Undoing Changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo).

Comment: How can I commit as a new revision?

Comment: @CorkKochi Read http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo and http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html

Comment: Please check @Petesh comment

Comment: @CorkKochi read the linked doc about undoing changes, please.

Answer (score 1):

Its not really needed to re-write the history and there is no real feature in svn too. Its always good to maintain the entire history. So the possible solution would be, Modify the changes and commit back which will create one more revisions.